# I'm struggling to create arrays with a depth of X

Tags: php

For testing purposes, I have to create arrays with a given depth.

Is there a simple way to create them?

Edit : sorry for the too broad question, my bad.

In order to test a method which tells the depth of a given array, the depth being the maximum number of dimensions an array can have, I need a function which can create an array with a given depth.

I'd want for instance a function  whose result would be something like this, for a depth value of 3 :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )
        )

)
```

Comment: we need way more information, please provide an example of what you are looking for and what you have attempted code wise

Comment: Please  tell more specifically about this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What do you mean by *"depth"* here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a recursive function like this:

```
<?php

$a = array();

function add_level($a, $nb) {
    $to_add = array();
    if ($nb -- > 0) {
        $to_add = add_level($to_add, $nb);
    }
    $a['child'] = $to_add;
    return $a;
}

print_r(add_level($a, 5));


?>
```

Output is

```
Array
(
    [child] => Array
        (
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [child] => Array
                        (
                            [child] => Array
                                (
                                    [child] => Array
                                        (
                                            [child] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```